# Binding data using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView to display data. But, When I am trying to bind data in onBindViewHolder() method, I am getting following error...

```
09-12 16:37:51.217    2166-2166/com.zaptech.databasedemowithrecycler E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x17
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3769)
            at com.zaptech.databasedemowithrecycler.adapter.MyEmployeeAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyEmployeeAdapter.java:47)
            at com.zaptech.databasedemowithrecycler.adapter.MyEmployeeAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyEmployeeAdapter.java:24)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5277)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5310)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4568)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4461)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1962)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1371)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1334)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:563)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2847)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3145)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:493)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code for My adapter is as follows which also include ViewHolder class:

```
public class MyEmployeeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyEmployeeAdapter.EmployeeViewHolder> {
private List<ModelEmployee> empItemList;
private Context mContext;

public MyEmployeeAdapter(Context context, List<ModelEmployee> feedItemList) {
    this.empItemList = feedItemList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public EmployeeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout_emp, null);

    EmployeeViewHolder viewHolder = new EmployeeViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EmployeeViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ModelEmployee feedItem = empItemList.get(position);
    Log.d("NAME : ", feedItem.getName());
    Log.d("AGE : ", String.valueOf(feedItem.getAge()));
    holder.txtName.setText(feedItem.getName());
    holder.txtAge.setText(feedItem.getAge());

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != empItemList ? empItemList.size() : 0);
}

public class EmployeeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView txtName;
    public TextView txtAge;

    public EmployeeViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        this.txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        this.txtAge = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.age);
    }
}
}
```

Stuck in the following lines :

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EmployeeViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ModelEmployee feedItem = empItemList.get(position);
    Log.d("NAME : ", feedItem.getName());
    Log.d("AGE : ", String.valueOf(feedItem.getAge()));
    holder.txtName.setText(feedItem.getName());
    holder.txtAge.setText(feedItem.getAge());

}
```

Please, Let me about wrong thing happen to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
holder.txtAge.setText(feedItem.getAge());
```

To

```
holder.txtAge.setText(String.valueOf(feedItem.getAge()));
```

You are passing integer value in setText method so it will check in String.xml file for string. So you have to convert integer value to String value.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me to find out my silly mistake. Its working fine now...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that android interpreted your `feedItem.getAge()` as resource ID and tried to fetch a corresponding string resource from `string.xml`.

Therefore a runtime exception was thrown (resource not found), instead of a compiler error.